# Modifying a 2D array in a function using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference

I'm having some problems with a function I've written to initialize a 2D grid for an implementation of Conway's Game of Life. This function *initialize(bool*, int, int)* uses pointer arithmetic to access all the values in the 2d array whose pointer I'm passing.

main.cpp

```
#include "logic.cpp"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;

const unsigned int WIDTH = 640;
const unsigned int HEIGHT = 640;
const int RESOLUTION = 10;

const int rows = (WIDTH/RESOLUTION) - 1;
const int cols = (HEIGHT/RESOLUTION) - 1;

int main()
{
    bool curr_gen[rows][cols];
    bool next_gen[rows][cols];

    bool* curr = &curr_gen[0][0];
    bool* next = &next_gen[0][0];

    initialize(curr, rows, cols);

    /*sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), "Conway's Game of Life");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

logic.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

void initialize(bool* p, int r, int c)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
             if(rand()% 2)
                *(*(p+i)+j) = true;
             else
                *(*(p+i)+j) = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The errors I'm getting all say *invalid type argument of unary '*'(have 'int')*. The way I see it, (*(p+i)+j) gives an address of a 2d array element (&arr[i][j]), and on dereferencing that, I can access arr[i][j] and change it. I'd really appreciate it if someone could please point out the mistake in my reasoning. I'm using the GNU GCC compiler in Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at your code logic:

```
*(*(p+i)+j) = true;
```

This attempts to be equivalent to `p[i][j]` and it *actually is*. The problem is that `p` is not a `bool[][]`. It's not even a `bool**`. It is a `bool*`, which is a pointer to `bool`, which additionally might also be the first element of an array.

Note that what I am about to explain is valid *only* for `T[][]` arrays. It is not valid for dynamically allocated array that has it's rows also dynamically allocated.

What I am going to explain bases on the fact that a two (or three, or four...) dimentional array is implemented as a one, big, one-dimentional array. If you have `bool[3][3]` it's actually `bool[9]` under the hood, with some benefits regarding access syntax (in form of `[x][y]` access).

Now let's take a look at your code once again:

```
for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
    {
         if(rand()% 2)
            *(*(p+c)+j) = true;
         else
            *(*(p+c)+j) = false;
    }
}
```

Your outer `for()` loop iterates through rows of the array. Your inner `for()` loop iterates over the elements of a single row.

If you have passed a `bool**` as `p`, it would *actually work*! But you did not. You passed a `bool*`, which indicates single array. You take advantage of implementation detail of `T[][]` (two-dimentional array) in form of working with it as though it was a bigger `T[]`.

What you now want is to access `i`th row and `j`th element. To do so, you have to:

- drop double dereferencing. You are working with one-dimentional array
- fix your logic regarding the position of the interested element

A simple fix would be changing this:

```
*(*(p+i)+j) = true;
```

to this:

```
*(p+i*c+j) = true;
```

The second one dereferences the element that is in the `i`th row (you have to multiply `i` by `c`, because e.g. the first element of the third row is the `3*c`th element of your one-dimentional representation of your two-dimentional array) and at the position `j`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dereference the pointer twice. You only have a `bool*`, not a `bool**`.

Use `*(p+i*c+j)`.

Comment: `i` should be multiplied by `r`, not `j`. And there is no `bool**` involved

Comment: Actually `c`, not `r`.

Comment: no, it should be `r`, not `c`. `r` represents rows and the `i` counter represents iteration over rows. Every time you change a row, your memory shifts by `r` positions. That's why you need to multiply `i` by `r`. `j` is responsible for iterating over single elements of a given row (or - iterating through columns of a given row).

Comment: Every time you change row, you shift by `c` columns, so 1 row, not `r` columns.

Comment: True that. Brain farts happen :>

Comment: No worries, happens to me all the time ;)